# Azure devops - is it possible to export test plan to csv , or all test cases via rest api?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to create a backup system from a pipeline to our project.
I know it is possible to download a single test case to csv via the export button:

[image]

So I was wondering is it possible to do the same for the test plan, but via rest api?
Or is there a workaround to export all of the test cases?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't have a directly way to achieve this.

But via code you will be able to export the information.

The idea to solve the problem is as follows:

1. [Get Test Plan information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test-plans/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&tabs=HTTP)
2. [Get Test Suite information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test-suites/get-test-suite-by-id?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&tabs=HTTP)
3. [Get Test Case information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test-suites/get-test-case-by-id?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&tabs=HTTP)
4. Use the test case workitem above the code query and save the information as csv.